# how to loop data from txt database?

Tags: php, database

i'm working with txt database, here my code:

```
    <div class="somdtnecmtx">ikuti kami di&nbsp;
        <?php
  $txt_file    = file_get_contents('dbmenuecom.txt');
  $rows        = explode("\n", $txt_file);
  array_shift($rows);
$i=1;
  foreach($rows as $row => $data)
  {
 
    $row_data = explode('|', $data);   
    $somedid = $row_data[0];
    $somedtb = $row_data[1];
    $somedps = $row_data[2];
    $somedjd = $row_data[3];
    $somedlk = $row_data[4];
    $somedic = $row_data[5];
    $somedcl = $row_data[6];
    $somedac = $row_data[7];
  echo '<a href="'. $somedlk .'" title="'. $somedjd .'"><i class="'. $somedic .'" style="'. $somedcl .'"></i></a>'; }?> 
    </div>
```

but I get this error on result:

> ikuti kami di **fb ig tw** Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in
> D:\XAMPP\htdocs\mediaol\draftweb.prefix\halecom.php on line 76
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in
> D:\XAMPP\htdocs\mediaol\draftweb.prefix\halecom.php on line 77
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in
> D:\XAMPP\htdocs\mediaol\draftweb.prefix\halecom.php on line 78
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in
> D:\XAMPP\htdocs\mediaol\draftweb.prefix\halecom.php on line 79
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in
> D:\XAMPP\htdocs\mediaol\draftweb.prefix\halecom.php on line 80
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in
> D:\XAMPP\htdocs\mediaol\draftweb.prefix\halecom.php on line 81
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in
> D:\XAMPP\htdocs\mediaol\draftweb.prefix\halecom.php on line 82

where did wrong of my code?

Comment: Please provide `dbmenuecom.txt` rows sample

Comment: ID|TABEL|POS|JUDUL|LINK|ICON|CLASS|AKTIVASI
001|menusos|001|facebook|#|fa fa-facebook-square|font-size:20px;padding-right:10px;|1
002|menusos|002|instagram|#|fa fa-instagram|font-size:20px;padding-right:10px;|1
003|menusos|003|twitter|#|fa fa-twitter-square|font-size:20px;padding-right:10px;|1

Answer (score 1):

Your code works when you have well formatted data: [example here](https://phpize.online/?phpses=f9870f2e1e15341382e0850a271d04ba&sqlses=null&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80) but in case data not match to desired format your code failed.
So you need to add simple checker in your code:

```
foreach($rows as $row => $data) {
    $row_data = explode('|', $data);   
    $somedid = isset($row_data[0]) ? $row_data[0] : '';
    $somedtb = isset($row_data[1]) ? $row_data[1] : '';
    $somedps = isset($row_data[2]) ? $row_data[2] : '';
    $somedjd = isset($row_data[3]) ? $row_data[3] : '';
    $somedlk = isset($row_data[4]) ? $row_data[4] : '';
    $somedic = isset($row_data[5]) ? $row_data[5] : '';
    $somedcl = isset($row_data[6]) ? $row_data[6] : '';
    $somedac = isset($row_data[7]) ? $row_data[7] : '';
    echo '<a href="'. $somedlk .'" title="'. $somedjd .'"><i class="'. $somedic .'" style="'. $somedcl .'"></i></a>'; 
}
```

or another checker:

```
foreach($rows as $row => $data) {
    $row_data = explode('|', $data); 
    if (is_array($row_data) && count($row_data) == 8) {
        $somedid = $row_data[0];
        $somedtb = $row_data[1];
        $somedps = $row_data[2];
        $somedjd = $row_data[3];
        $somedlk = $row_data[4];
        $somedic = $row_data[5];
        $somedcl = $row_data[6];
        $somedac = $row_data[7];
        echo '<a href="'. $somedlk .'" title="'. $somedjd .'"><i class="'. $somedic .'" style="'. $somedcl .'"></i></a>'; 
    } else {
        echo "wrong row format";
    }

}
```

[Live PHPize.online code here](https://phpize.online/?phpses=2d2f279fdcf9f800b31e8d62781277fb&sqlses=null&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80)

Comment: Try the second variant, it looks better

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the name of txt files do not contain spaces.Like as: new file.txt, combine the words with underscore (new_file.txt) and then run the loop.